# Slashcommands doesn't work with my discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

i posted a question before 'my discord.js bot doesn't reply to a user message even if there isn't any error'. Well, the solution works but just with messages, not with commmands.

I'm also activing `applications.commands` scope in OAuth2 of the bot.

I'm working on node 16.7.0 and these are installed packages :

- discord.js@dev 13.2.0
- @discordjs/builders 0.5.0
- @discordjs/rest 0.1.0-canary.0
- discord-api-types 0.22.0
- dotenv 10.0.0
- fs 0.0.1-security

the console doesn't show any error message but it shows these and it means that it's working :

```
Started refreshing application (/) commands.
Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.
Ready! Logged in as {mydiscord_bot_tag}
```

these are the file of my bot:

```
discord-bot/
├── node_modules
├── .env
├── public/
    |── index.js
    └── functions/
        |──handleCommands.js
        └──handleEvents.js
    └── events/
        |──interactionCreate.js
        └──ready.js
    └── commands/
        |── Information/
            └── ping.js
        └── Moderation
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

index.js's code

```javascript
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new Client({ intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.commands = new Collection();

const functions = fs.readdirSync('./src/functions').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const commandsFolder = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

client.once('ready', () => {
    client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: 'i am stuck ' }], status: 'dnd' });
});

(async () => {
    for (const file of functions) {
        require(`./functions/${file}`)(client);
    }
    client.handleEvents(eventFiles, './src/commands');
    client.handleCommands(commandsFolder, './src/events');
    client.login(process.env.token);
})();
```

functions/handleCommands.js's code

```javascript
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');

const clientId = '878988418665816156';
const guildId = '879887194268008520';

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async (commandsFolders, path) => {
        client.commandArray = [];
        for (const folder of commandsFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${path}/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                client.commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON);
            }
        }
        const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);

        (async () => {
            try {
                console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

                await rest.put(
                    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
                    { body: client.commandArray },
                );

                console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })();
    };
};
```

functions/handleEvents.js's code

```javascript
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleEvents = async (eventFiles) => {
        for (const file of eventFiles) {
            const event = require(`../events/${file}`);
            if (event.once) {
                client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
            }
            else {
                client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
            }
        }
    };
};
```

events/interactionCreate.js's code

```javascript
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return;

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    },
};
```

events/ready.js

```javascript
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    execute(client) {
        console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    },
};
```

commands/Information/ping.js's code

```javascript
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

So sorry about all these huge codes they was my whole folder :")

I hope reciving an answer, thanks already!

Comment: It’s best to only include the relevant code. Having all the files makes the question unnecessarily long.

Comment: i thought that the issue will be in a file of those, that's why i puted all thsese codes

Answer (score 1):

I think too that @user16[…] ‘s method is easier, but
When you use `SlashCommandBuilder`, you don’t need the builders subfolder at your defining.
So instead this:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
```

Try this:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
```

Here an easy example (even if your code hasn’t any problem):

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

And documentation: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#individual-command-files

Answer (score 0):

this is the event which is triggered on a message.

```
client.on("message",message => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

i dont see this event in your code anywhere

Comment: it show me some information in code like channelId and username but even that it still  doesn't work

Comment: and also it shows me that i have to change 'message' to 'messagecCreate'

Answer (score 0):

I used this (without builder):

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'yourCommand') {
    await interaction.reply({
    //your code
  });
  }
});
```